# Woocommerce related products by proximity from single lat,lng meta field

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, geolocation, geocode

I'm looking to display Woocommerce related products on the single product page by proximity/distance. All the products have a field `martygeocoderlatlng` with the lattitude and longitude stored as a comma separated value `(27.903549,-82.846774)`

The field is created from the Address Geocoder plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/address-geocoder/

"Access your data in the loop using the following functions, with the post ID passed as a parameter. For the full coordinates (in brackets):"

```
echo get_geocode_latlng( $post->ID );
```

Any insight would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
/**
 * Output the related products.
 */
function woocommerce_output_related_products() {

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 4,
        'columns'        => 4,
        'orderby'        => 'rand', // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine.
    );

    woocommerce_related_products( apply_filters(       'woocommerce_output_related_products_args', $args ) );
}
```

Comment: How did you create `martygeocoderlatlng` field?

Comment: @KashifRafique Adress Geocoder https://wordpress.org/plugins/address-geocoder/